# Moving roles switches them

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I want my bot to create five roles and to order them in a specific way at a specific position.

Therefore, I am looping through a list of names and creating the roles accordingly. (This is not my actual code, but the idea behind it is the same.)

```
for (String name : roleNames) {
    event.getGuild().createRole().setColor(color).setName(name).queue(role -> {
    role.getGuild().modifyRolePositions().selectPosition(role.getPosition()).moveTo(role.getGuild().getRoles().size()-8).queue()});
}
```

To clear things up, I try to move the role by selecting its initial position `role.getPosition()` and moving it to a specific position `role.getGuild().getRoles().size()-8`.

Since the position of the highest role in the list equals the number of roles, every role created should be moved to the exact same spot, thus moving every role beneath it one position lower.

But that is not what is happening.

When executing these lines of code and slowing the process down (by using `Thread.sleep` and/or `.queueAfter()`) I witnessed the following:

1. The first role is created at the bottom. Everything is fine.
2. The first role is moved to the destined position. Works.
3. The second role is created at the bottom as usual.
4. When the second role moves up to the position, it moves the first role down to where it was created (at the bottom).

This behavior can be seen until every role is created.
The last role stays where it belongs (since no other role switches its position).

Is there a logical issue in my code, is my way of doing this the wrong solution or is this just a discord issue? How can I possibly work around this behavior?

If you suspect this to be deeper rooted in my code please let me know, for that I can provide you with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModifyRolePosition uses a cached version of the roles.

Changing only one position at a time results in the same cached version being modified everytime, which leads to the changes not being carried over.

That is why it is possible to make multiple manipulations on one call, by simply queuing multiple `.selectPosition(initialPosition).moveTo(newPosition)` together and committing them by calling `.queue()` once at the end.